# Finding N closest numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

Have a  2-dimensional array, like -

```
a[0] = [ 0 , 4 , 9 ]
a[1] = [ 2 , 6 , 11 ]
a[2] = [ 3 , 8 , 13 ]
a[3] = [ 7 , 12 ]
```

Need to select one element from each of the sub-array in a way that the resultant set of numbers are closest, that is the difference between the highest number and lowest number in the set is minimum.

The answer to the above will be = `[ 9 , 6 , 8 , 7 ]`.

Have made an algorithm, but don't feel its a good one.
What would be a efficient algorithm to do this in terms of time and space complexity?

**EDIT - My Algorithm** (in python)-

```
INPUT - Dictionary : table{}
OUTPUT - Dictionary : low_table{}
#
N = len(table)
for word_key in table:
    for init in table[word_key]:
        temp_table = copy.copy(table)
        del temp_table[word_key]
        per_init = copy.copy(init)
        low_table[init]=[]
        for ite in range(N-1):
            min_val = 9999
            for i in temp_table:
                for nums in temp_table[i]:
                    if min_val > abs(init-nums):
                        min_val = abs(init-nums)
                        del_num = i
                        next_num = nums
            low_table[per_init].append(next_num)
            init = (init+next_num)/2
            del temp_table[del_num]
lowest_val = 99
lowest_set = []
for x in low_table:
    low_table[x].append(x)
    low_table[x].sort()
    mini = low_table[x][-1]-low_table[x][0]
    if mini < lowest_val:
        lowest_val = mini
        lowest_set = low_table[x]
print lowest_set
```

Comment: Show us your algorithm.

Comment: This reminds me of a knapsack problem, might be NP-complete

Comment: Not sure how this is the Knapsack problem. Care to elaborate?

Comment: It's not the knapsack problem, but seems similar.  knapsack says choose items that fit in the knapsack so that some value is maximal.  This says choose one item from each bag to put in your knapsack such that something is minimized. It's like a partitioned Knapsack problem.

Comment: Are the rows guaranteed to be sorted?  That kind of matters.

Comment: I think it might even be worth trying a sequence alignment on this as preprocessing

Comment: Have added my algorithm.

Comment: Yes the rows are sorted.

Comment: what would be the solution for `a[1] = [0];  a[2] = [23,45];  a[3] = [50];  a[4] = [100]` ?

Comment: @groovy: or even `a[1] = [0,10]`, `a[2] = [4,6]` (I was thinking along similar lines).

Comment: @cjrh wouldn't the answers `[0,4]` and `[6,10]` be equally valid?

Comment: @groovy if you mean multiple solutions that satisfy the criteria, why not add some way to break ties -- for example "pick left-most if two choices are equally valid"? it sounds like a common sense way to break ties. or did i miss something of substance?

Comment: @groovy: yeah, sorry, I misread your comment.  I was thinking about how to deal with multiple solutions.  For large datasets there could be many.

Comment: @groovy for `a[1] = [0]; a[2] = [23,45]; a[3] = [50]; a[4] = [100]` , both `[0,23,50,100]` and `[0,45,50,100]` are correct.

Comment: for `a[1] = [0,10], a[2] = [4,6]`. `[0,4]` and `[10,6]` are  the solutions.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey I don't see it. With knapsack you need to pick from **a set** of items within some **capacity** to **maximize value**. With this you're given **a few sets** of items where you have to pick **exactly one from each**, you have to **minimize the difference** between them and there's **no capacity**. The only thing they really seem to have in common is that you pick items, and there's more than enough algorithms that does that.

Comment: @randomstring I was just trying to clarify if any differences other than the highest/lowest were important.

Comment: @Dukeling: the number of items IS a form of capacity.  And instead of maximizing value, you minimize a range.  Is it precisely the knapsack problem? no, but I never claimed it was, just said it reminded me of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

collect all the values to create a single ordered sequence, with each element tagged with the array it came from:
0(0), 2(1), 3(2), 4(0), 6(1), ... 12(3), 13(2)

then create a window across them, starting with the first (0(0)) and ending it at the first position that makes the window span all the arrays (0(0) -> 7(3))

then roll this window by incrementing the start of the window by one, and increment the end of the window until you again have a window that covers all elements.

then roll it again: (2(1), 3(2), 4(0), ... 7(3)), and so forth.

at each step keep track of the the difference between the largest and the smallest. Eventually you find the one with the smallest window. I have the feeling that in the worst case this is O(n^2) but that's just a guess.

Comment: wouldn't it be `O(n.log(n))` for the sorting, and then just `O(n)` for the sliding window? that's because the pointers are never decremented. you can only have max `2.n` possible windows.

Comment: If the original lists are sorted (as in the example given) then combining the lists into one sorted list is linear time.

Comment: You probably want to keep a hash from the array id (which of the different arrays the number comes from) to the count in the window. Then you know when to move the front index, and when to move the back index.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Had to add little more features while moving the back index of the window.

Comment: @DaveGalvin cool, even better -- `O(n)` all the way! round of upvotes please to our relatively new whiterook6 =)

Answer (score 2):

A wordy Haskell version of the nice algorithm by whiterook6:

```
import Data.List (minimumBy,sortBy)
import qualified Data.Map as M (fromList,toList,adjust,lookup)

f arrays = g (zip arrays [1..]) [] h [(100,0),(0,0)] where
  n = length arrays
  h = (M.fromList $ zip [1..n] (repeat 0))
  g arrays sequence indexes best
    | any ((==0) . snd) (M.toList indexes) = 
        g (foldr comb [] arrays) (next:sequence) (M.adjust (+1) ind indexes) best
    | otherwise = 
        if null (drop 1 arrays) 
           then best'
           else g (foldr comb [] arrays) 
                  (next:init trimmedSequence) 
                  (foldr (M.adjust (+1)) h (ind : (map snd $ init trimmedSequence))) 
                  best'
   where 
     best' = minimumBy comp [best,trimmedSequence]
     next@(val,ind) = minimum $ map (\(arr,i) -> (head arr,i)) arrays
     comb a@(seq,i) b = if i == ind 
                           then if null (drop 1 seq) 
                                   then b 
                                   else (drop 1 seq,i) : b 
                           else a : b
     comp a b = compare (fst (head a) - fst (last a)) (fst (head b) - fst (last b))
     trimSequence []     _ = []
     trimSequence (x:xs) h
       | any ((==0) . snd) (M.toList h) = 
           case M.lookup (snd x) h of
             Just 0     -> x : trimSequence xs (M.adjust (+1) (snd x) h)
             otherwise  -> trimSequence xs h
       | otherwise                      = []
     trimmedSequence = trimSequence sequence (M.fromList $ zip [1..n] (repeat 0))
```

Output:

```
*Main> f [[0,4,9],[2,6,11],[3,8,13],[7,12]]
[(9,1),(8,3),(7,4),(6,2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a variant of whiterook's algorithm that I think is simpler (and apart from an initial sort step, it's more clearly O(N)).

Iterate minval through all the values in order. While doing this, we keep the index of the smallest value in each array which are greater than or equal to minval). We also keep the maximum value of the elements at these index in their corresponding arrays.

When we've done considering a particular minval, we can increment the index for all the arrays that contain minval, and update the maxval if necessary.

Here's an implementation. Note that (except for the initial sort) it's O(N) because the inner loop is executed at most once per value in each array.

```
def minspan(aa):
    allnums = sorted(set(sum(aa, [])))
    ntoi = dict((x, []) for x in allnums)
    for i in xrange(len(aa)):
        for x in aa[i]:
            ntoi[x].append(i)
    indexes = [0] * len(aa)
    maxval = max(a[0] for a in aa)
    best = None
    for minval in allnums:
        if best is None or best[0] > maxval - minval:
            best = maxval - minval, minval, maxval
        for i in ntoi[minval]:
            indexes[i] += 1
            if indexes[i] >= len(aa[i]):
                return [min(x for x in a if x >= best[1]) for a in aa]
            maxval = max(maxval, aa[i][indexes[i]])

aa = [[0,4,9], [2,6,11], [3,8,13], [7,12]]
print minspan(aa)
```